# I'm not getting data in the next fragment sent from another fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have tried to refer the similar questions but I couldn't get the solution. Actually I am trying to send a string from one fragment to another but in next fragment while receiving data it's showing null point exception error.

My Code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
 switch(view.getId()){
 case R.id.proceed_button:
           user_email=editText.getText().toString().trim();
           frag_two si=new frag_two();
           Bundle args=new Bundle();
           args.putString("this_email",user_email);
           si.setArguments(args);
           break;}}
 public String sendString(){
    return emailT.getText().toString().trim();
}
```

Container Activity:
   (Inside a method)
          frag gi=new frag();
        String email_id=gi.sendString();

Comment: Instead String email_id=gi.sendString(); do gi.sendString(email_id); but for your question interface is the answer

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

For inter fragment or fragment to activity communication, you should use interface and callback listener like [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

For Activity to fragment:

Try this in your onCreate() method, check [this](http://www.journaldev.com/9266/android-fragment-lifecycle) for more info

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    String myString = bundle.getString("this_email");
}
```

Easy way, I would pass it in my constructor or create a method after constructor in case it is being over loaded.

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {  

private String mString;

public TestFragment {

}

public void sendString(String str){
  this.mString = str;

}
```

}

And in Activity,

```
TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();
testFragment.sendString(user_email);
# add other codes
```

Comment: sir I've tried to replicate you in some ways but still showing error please check my edit

Comment: try interface to send it from fragment to activity

Comment: Actually I'm a bit confused in using interface.So, it'll be really helpful if you can demonstrate that a bit

Comment: the link in the answer thoroughly explains it from basics